# fail to run program on anaconda prompt

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, mnist

I install tensorflow by anaconda and successfully get the message "Hello Tensorflow!" message after type in"print(sess.run(hello))". However, when I tried the tutorial program from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py
 but results in (I did input `activate tensorflow` beforehand):

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data 
ModuleNotFoundError:No module named 'tensorflow'"
```

Also, another problem occurs when I tried to run my classmate's program. 
result in:

```
import cv2 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."
```

My OS is windows 10
NVIDIA 765M
tensorflow version：1.3.0

Comment: I solved the second problem. However, it is strange that the program will report error " Import tensorflow as tf ModuleNotFoundError: No module named tensorflow" while in python(after activated tensorflow) the "import tensorflow as tf" actually works.

Comment: So you're saying you input `activate tensorflow` meaning your installation of `tensorflow` is in an Anaconda environment. How are you running this code? Are you sure it's running inside your virtual environment? It sounds like you've written this in a text editor, and that text editor is running with a different python version/in a different environment.